# scikit-learn add extra data to SGDClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm trying to do text classification with `scikit-learn`.

I have text that does not classify well. I think I can improve the predictions by adding data I can deduce in the form of an array of integers.

For example, sample 1 would come with `[3, 1, 5, 2]` and sample 2 would come with `[2, 1, 4, 2]`. This would also be true of the test data.

The idea is that the classifier could use both the text and the numbers to classify the data.

I've read the documentation for scikit learn and I can't find how to do it. It must be possible because all that is classified, internally, is vectors of numbers. So adding another vector of numbers should not be that much of a problem, but I can't figure out how. `partial_fit` adds more samples, it does not add more information about the existing samples. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do. I tried to combine `GaussianNB` with `SGDClassifier`, but it turns out I don't know how to do that. (Was it a bad idea?)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could add this new feature as another dimension to your training data. You need to modify the training data by adding your new features before calling SGD.

**A simple/naive way would be:**

For example, if my training data with two samples were
`X = [ [1,2,3], [8,9,0] ]`

And my new features for each sample was
`new_feature_X = [ [11,22,33] , [77,88,00] ]`

My new training data would be:

`X_new = [[1,2,3,11,22,33] , [8,9,0,77,88,00]]`

Then you call `SGD.fit(X_new, labels)`

As far as my SGD knowledge goes, I don't think there is any other way to combine two features.

> The idea is that the classifier could use both the text and the
>   numbers to classify the data.

I find a neural network to be much more suitable for this. You could use two input layers, one for text vectors, and one for the numbers and feed them together into a network to get the output.

> I tried to combine GaussianNB with SGDClassifier, but it turns out I
>   don't know how to do that. (Was it a bad idea?)

SGD means stochastic **gradient** descent. Is it possible to find the gradient of NaiveBayes?  Whats the corresponding cost function ?

> What should I do?

1. Ensemble. Train two separate classifiers. One using your text data, and another one for your new handcrafted feature. And then take the average of their prediction probabilities. You could train multiple classifier and take their votes. This [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/new-data-set-training-nltk-tutorial/) is great for that.
2. Try out MLP Classifier. I used it a while ago, and found it works pretty great with text.
3. Neural networks. It's pretty easy with [Keras](https://keras.io).
4. Read research literature. There is pretty good chance academia might have done some work on your dataset. Try to read some of them. Google scholar, semantic scholar are great places to find published reseaerch.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense,Concatenate
from keras.models import Model

# This returns a tensor
text_input_vec = Input(shape=(784,))
new_numeric_feature = Input(shape=(4,))

# feed your text to a dense layer
dense1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(text_input_vec)

# feed your numeric feature to another dense layer
dense2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(new_numeric_feature)

# concatenate/combine the output of both
concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)([dense1,dense2])

# use the above to predict the label of your text. Layer below
# assumes you have 2 classes 
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(concat)

model = Model(inputs=[text_input_vec,new_numeric_feature], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Comment: I think I can use a neural network with scikit-learn. I tried Keras before and I don't know enough about the algorithms named in the documentation to use it effectively.